# R: tapply(length) giving differing results with NAs

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, na, tapply

I'm getting different results from tapply with subsetted arguments that include NAs depending on whether I use

```
tapply(X[X==Y], IND[X==Y], length)
```

or

```
tapply(X, IND, function(x){length(x[x==Y])})
```

Intro: `length()` with NAs does not behave according to naive expectations:

```
> vec <- c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,NA,8,NA,10)
> length(vec)
[1] 10
> length(is.na(vec))  # Not talking about the same vector
[1] 10
> length(vec[vec==1])  # Sometimes I forget what vector I meant
[1] 4
```

Surprises for the unwary but it works this way for reasons; this is the expected behavior.  But the second, longer `tapply()` call above follows this pattern while the first version gives the naive expectation.

Setup:

```
set.seed(668)
yrCodes <- c(1995:2015)
staCodes <- c(LETTERS[1:12])
sexCodes <- c('m','f')
years <- rep(yrCodes, times=rep(sample(1:4, length(yrCodes), replace=TRUE)))
stations <- sample(staCodes, length(years), replace=TRUE)
sexes <- sample(sexCodes, length(years), replace=TRUE)
sexes[sample(1:length(sexes),10)] <- NA
data <- data.frame(YEAR=years, STATION=stations, SEX=sexes)
```

First form:

```
> with(data, tapply(SEX, STATION, length))  # All observations
A B C D E F G H I J K L 
4 5 7 4 3 6 2 3 3 4 6 4 
> with(data, tapply(SEX[SEX=='m'], STATION[SEX=='m'], length))  # Males
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L 
 2  3  4  3 NA  2  2  3  2  2  2  2 
> with(data, tapply(SEX[SEX=='f'], STATION[SEX=='f'], length))  # Females
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L 
 1  1  1 NA  3  2 NA NA  1  1  3  1 
> with(data, tapply(SEX[is.na(SEX)], STATION[is.na(SEX)], length))  # NAs
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L 
 1  1  2  1 NA  2 NA NA NA  1  1  1
```

This is what the unwary would expect, but it doesn't match what happens with `length(vec[])` above.  This, however, does:

```
> with(data, tapply(SEX, STATION, function(sex){length(sex[sex=='m'])}))  # Males plus NAs
A B C D E F G H I J K L 
3 4 6 4 0 4 2 3 2 3 3 3 
> with(data, tapply(SEX, STATION, function(sex){length(sex[sex=='f'])}))  # Females plus NAs
A B C D E F G H I J K L 
2 2 3 1 3 4 0 0 1 2 4 2 
> with(data, tapply(SEX, STATION, function(sex){length(sex[is.na(sex)])}))  # NAs
A B C D E F G H I J K L 
1 1 2 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Maybe the reason for the difference is given in the infamous tapply docs but I can't figure it out.  What's going on here?

Edit: Oh yeah -- also I notice the second way produces zeroes where the first only gives NAs; must be a significant difference in the call to `length` -- but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because subsetting with `NA` will yield `NA`

```
"m" == NA
[1] NA
```

and in your calls you do it in different places.

Consider this:

```
split(c(1,2,3), factor(c(1,2,3)))
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 2

$`3`
[1] 3
```

but with `NA` in the factor:

```
split(c(1,2,3), factor(c(1,2,NA)))
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 2
```

`split` automatically omits the `NA`s, and `split` is the main part of `tapply`.

Let's look at two of the `tapply`s you used:

```
with(data, tapply(SEX[SEX=='m'], STATION[SEX=='m'], length))
```

Here, you subset **before** passing to `tapply`. Thus, the values of `STATION` where `SEX` is `NA` will now be `NA` as well, and `split` will automatically omit them.

```
split(data$SEX[data$SEX == "m"], as.factor(as.numeric(data$STATION[data$SEX == "m"])))
```

The other one:

```
with(data, tapply(SEX, STATION, function(sex){length(sex[sex=='m'])}))
```

Here, you subset **after** passing to `tapply`, and

`split(c(1, NA, 2), factor(c(1, 2, 3)))` will of course still include the `NA` value.

```
split(data$SEX, as.factor(as.numeric(data$STATION)))
```

yields, e.g. for the first factor

```
[1] f    m    m    <NA>
Levels: f m
```

And, as you also mentioned, `NA == "m"` will be `NA`. Which is why you keep the `NA` this way.

```
c(2, 3, 4)[c(1, NA)]
[1]  2 NA
```

Comment: Excellent answer -- thanks!  I get it.  Alas for the unwary though; it seems like quite a gotcha, and I've seen no docs, tips, warnings or anything that would have led me to expect this.  `?tapply` makes no mention of `split`, and `?split` doesn't say anything about automatic NA omission (in a way that I can puzzle out).  Anyway, really nice explanation and I'd +1 if I could, but I'm TOO PUNY.